# How implement in app purchase dependent to application account instead of Google Play Account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

My app has two type users - basic & pro. User register is as basic user. User type will change from basic to pro after in app purchase.

I have follow sample code to implement this. I had register a product at play store & update a version of app on alpha channel play store.

Issue- I have login in my application with a basic user account 'A' & pay for pro version. Now user 'A' is Pro.

But when I logout of app & login in my application with other basic account 'B' & then click to  upgrade button. But in app purchase dialogue not open & I have received a message 'Item already owned'.

In app purchase became dependent to  Google Play Account instead of application account.

Is any way to make it to dependent to application account, not to Google Play account.

Comment: @mukhesh Did you find any solutions?

Comment: @shantanu, consume managed products after purchase

Answer (score 1):

Having just done this my understanding is that is how it works, the in-app purchase account is the account the device is logged into Google Play with, not the user login of the App. I would assume, though, that there would be an API method of logging in to Google Play within your App, but I don't know.

Comment: thanks for answer. There is no Api method of logging in to Google pay in my App.